# Firebase onAuthStateChanged initially setting user to null causing redirection of page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am using firebase, zustand and react-router-dom v6.6. The idea is a simple login page and one authenticated route which is accessible only when the user is logged in. When I log in I am successfully redirected to dashboard. The problem is when I refresh the dashboard page, user is redirected to login page inspite of being logged in. I suspect this is because when page is refreshed, initial value of user is set to null. How can I get around this behavior?

```
function App() {
  const setUserData = useUserStore((state) => state.setUser);
  const userData = useUserStore((state) => state.username);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUserData(user.email);
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/login",
      element: <Login />,
    },
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      element: userData ? (
        <Dashboard username={userData} />
      ) : (
        <Navigate to="/login" />
      ),
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

```
function Dashboard() {
  const username = useUserStore((state) => state.username);
  if (!username) {
    console.log("no username");
  }
  return username ? <div>Hi, {username}</div> : console.log("no");
}
```

Comment: "I suspect this is because when page is refreshed, initial value of user is set to null." => This is indeed the case, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). It's up to you to manage this case.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec How can I get around it?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you precisely as I'm not versed in reactjs. It's not crystal clear in your code but but it seems that when the Auth Observer is triggered it triggers, in turn, a redirection. You need to avoid this redirection if `user` is `null`.

Comment: @Mises I am setting a global value for user inside onAuthStateChanged() function and nothing else. No redirection code is set inside onAuthStateChanged function

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: while `currentUser` may be `null` while auth is initializing, `onAuthStateChanged` will only fire once it has restored the auth state or has failed to do so. Since OP doesn't use `currentUser` they shouldn't see the transitionary `null` here afaict - unless `useUserStore` wraps that.

Comment: @vinDev: You may want to `console.log(user)` inside your `onAuthStateChanged` listener to verify your assumption about its initial value. If you do that, please edit your question to show us the updated code and its output.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I checked and its true. On reloading the page first it shows null and then shows the user value

Comment: Hmmm... it really shouldn't. For many years I thought it did, but one of the engineers once correct me on that and showed me that it only fires `onAuthStateChanged` for the first time after it's done restoring - or failed to restore. --- One option to consider would be to store a local value to flag that the user was logged in before, that you can read synchronously while Firebase is restoring the data. Michael explained this in a talk at I/O a few years ago too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwY6jkohseg&t=1311s

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I confirm I can experiment the behaviour you mention in your comment. If signed in, the value of the `user` object is never `null` in the Observer when reloading the page. Thanks for having drawn my attention on this, I had not detected this behaviour since I always check for user inside the Observer! :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When refreshing the page, the entire app unmounts and remounts again and the onAuthStateChanged is call again which is the reason why it initially shows null, I guess.